# Python Tkinter File Menu Options

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, py2app

Creating a Tk app results in a menu item "Run Widget Demo" (File > Run Widget Demo). I can't seem to find docs on how to remove this menu item. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/menu.html) you can use:

```
my_menu_object.delete(index1, index2=None)
```

Comment: Thanks Vicent, it appears that the menu I was getting was a default menu shown when one isn't created. Your answer led me to create my own men, removing all of the default menus.